# MVC checkbox not binding to model in EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, binding, mvc-editor-templates

I had to use an EditorTemplate instead of the conventional `Html.CheckBoxFor` for my purposes. In the process, I seemed to have messed up it's binding though. Is there a reason why the following is not binding to an incoming model?

```
<input data-val="true"
        data-val-required="The @Html.Raw(checkSuffix) field is required."
        id="@Html.Raw(checkId)"
        name="@Html.Raw(checkName)"
        type="checkbox"
        value="true">
<input name="@Html.Raw(checkName)"
        type="hidden"
        value="false">
<label for="@Html.Raw(checkId)"
        name="@Html.Raw(labelName)">
    <span class="fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
    @Model.Label
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.Label)
</label>
```

Note: the model binds properly on posting to the server, just not on page reload or postback.

Edit: Generated HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." id="Issues_0__IsChecked" name="Issues[0].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Issues[0].IsChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
<label for="Issues_0__IsChecked" name="Issues[0].Label">
    <span class="fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
    My Transmitting Computer/Server is not working
    <input id="Issues_0__Label" name="Issues[0].Label" type="hidden" value="My Transmitting Computer/Server is not working">
</label>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you manually creating the html instead of using the html helpers? And what is `checkName` and how does it relate to your model?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to style the checkbox using the html helper. I used `checkName` to create a unique name for each checkbox in a list of checkboxes.

Comment: Essentially I was just trying to replicate the behavior of the html helper

Comment: Your creating identical html as the `CheckBoxFor()` method would do if used as `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Issues[i].Count; i++) { @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Issues[i].IsChecked ....}` (except that the `CheckBoxFor()` will give correct 2 way model binding) And your not do any styling of the checkbox (do you mean the label?)

Comment: Good call Stephen. Replaced the inputs with the html helper and just styled the label. Binds properly now. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: The way I'm styling it, the label itself becomes the checkbox so I think I just got caught up in "overstyling" it. If you want to throw an answer on, I'll mark it accepted. Thanks man

Comment: Its late so I'll add something in the morning. But there are better ways to do this. Is the styled label element something you use regularly?

Comment: No. I'm very new to MVC. There's nothing I do regularly yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempting to manually create html with gives identical html as the `CheckBoxFor()` method, except that you never set the `checked` attribute so when the view is displayed (either initially or if you return the view in the POST method) all checkboxes will be unchecked.

You have not posted your models or the view, but it is also clear you not using your `EditorTemplate` correctly. Assuming your have the following models

```
public class MainModel
{
  public IEnumerable<NestedModel> Issues { get; set; }
}
public class NestedModel
{
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
  public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` create a partial view named `NestedModel.cshtml` (note the name must match the name of the class)

```
@model yourAssembly.NestedModel
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.IsSelected)"> // use IdFor() and no need to add name attribute
  <span class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x"></i>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Label)
</label>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Label)
```

and then in the main view

```
@model yourAssembly.MainModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Issues)
  ...
```

Note that the `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will generate the correct html (with indexers) for each item in the collection.

Its unclear why you have the property `Label` which just appears to return `"My Transmitting Computer/Server is not working"`. Instead your model should be

```
public class NestedModel
{
  [Display(Name = "My Transmitting Computer/Server is not working")]
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and in the `EditorTemplate`, replace `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Label)` with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsChecked)` and delete the hidden input.

Finally, if your regularly creating `<label>` with those icons, consider creating a HtmlHelper extension method so you you can simply  use (say) `@Html.MyCoolLabel(m => m.IsSelected)` to generate all the html.